# SELECT from nothing?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to have a statement like

```
SELECT "Hello world"
WHERE 1 = 1
```

in SQL?

The main thing I want to know, is can I SELECT from nothing, ie not have a FROM clause.

Comment: Looking at your comment on @Rafael Belliard, you may be better off asking what you actually want to do. Do you want to return some string if values exist for a given table for example?

Comment: Yes, that's actually exactly what I wanted.  I know that I can do it, I was more wondering if I needed a `FROM NULL` between `SELECT` and `WHERE`.  Obscure phrasing mostly because it's homework and I didn't want someone to come and tell me the answer if my gut feeling was wrong.

Answer (score 181):

It's not consistent across vendors - Oracle, MySQL, and DB2 support dual:

```
SELECT 'Hello world'
  FROM DUAL
```

...while SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and SQLite don't require the `FROM DUAL`:

```
SELECT 'Hello world'
```

MySQL does support both ways.

Comment: I've always wondered. Why the choice of the term dual for the phantom table?

Comment: @Alex: "The original DUAL table had two rows in it (hence its name), but subsequently it only had one row."

Comment: On DB2 dual is called 'sysibm.sysdummy1'

Comment: On Postgresql, it's possible to create a dummy table called `DUAL` and perform queries from a phantom-like table.

Comment: in DB2, note to use single quotes for literals to select and doublequotes for its alias (if set)

Comment: Apache Hive and Cloudera Impala also do not require a FROM clause.

Comment: Confusingly, MySQL supports both options, but only allows a `WHERE` clause if the dummy table is used.

Comment: @Stephan but why, do you need to run the exact same queries in different database implementations for some reason?

Comment: @Andy Here are a few examples : 
- you want to change the backend of a legacy application without spending too much time in rewriting existing SQL queries (migration from Oracle to Posgtresql)
- you are writing an application supporting different databases vendors and for limiting complexity you try to share as much as possible SQL queries among the various databases

Comment: @AlexBlakemore "I created the DUAL table as an underlying object in the Oracle Data Dictionary. It was never meant to be seen itself, but instead used inside a view that was expected to be queried. The idea was that you could do a JOIN to the DUAL table and create two rows in the result for every one row in your table. Then, by using GROUP BY, the resulting join could be summarized to show the amount of storage for the DATA extent and for the INDEX extent(s). The name, DUAL, seemed apt for the process of creating a pair of rows from just one" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table)

Comment: About Db2: FROM DUAL is a compatibility feature that must be enabled with DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR. Normally you select from sysibm.sysdummy1.
About MySQL: actually it's the opposite, FROM DUAL WHERE works as expected (though I never suspected it would be relevant...).

Answer (score 45):

Try this.

Single:

```
SELECT *  FROM (VALUES ('Hello world')) t1 (col1) WHERE 1 = 1
```

Multi:

```
SELECT *  FROM (VALUES ('Hello world'),('Hello world'),('Hello world')) t1 (col1) WHERE 1 = 1
```

more detail here : http://modern-sql.com/use-case/select-without-from

Comment: The only ANSI SQL compliant answer! (To a question with no dbms specified.)

Comment: What is the purpose of `WHERE 1 = 1`? On PostgreSQL works without it. Or it concerns another DMBS's?

Comment: Only `SELECT *  FROM (VALUES ("Hello world")) t1 (col1)` still fine. `Where` just answer for this question.

Comment: @chuongtv How do you select multiple rows?

Comment: @Hector Just follow struct insert of SQL. like this `SELECT *  FROM (VALUES ('Hello world'),('Hello world'),('Hello world')) t1 (col1) WHERE 1 = 1`

Comment: yoo thanks for the multi row example.

Answer (score 36):

In [**Oracle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table):

```
SELECT 'Hello world' FROM dual
```

[**Dual equivalent in SQL Server**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/07/20/sql-server-select-from-dual-dual-equivalent/):

```
SELECT 'Hello world'
```

Comment: Could I put a statement like `WHERE (SELECT ... )` after it?

Answer (score 14):

Here is the most complete list of database support of dual from https://blog.jooq.org/tag/dual-table/:

> In many other RDBMS, there is no need for dummy tables, as you can
>   issue statements like these:
>
> ```
> SELECT 1;
> SELECT 1 + 1;
> SELECT SQRT(2);
> ```
>
> These are the RDBMS, where the above is generally possible:
>
> - H2
> - MySQL
> - Ingres
> - Postgres
> - SQLite
> - SQL Server
> - Sybase ASE
>
> In other RDBMS, dummy tables are required, like in Oracle. Hence,
>   you’ll need to write things like these:
>
> ```
> SELECT 1       FROM DUAL;
> SELECT 1 + 1   FROM DUAL;
> SELECT SQRT(2) FROM DUAL;
> ```
>
> These are the RDBMS and their respective dummy tables:
>
> - DB2: SYSIBM.DUAL
> - Derby: SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
> - H2: Optionally supports DUAL
> - HSQLDB: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_USERS
> - MySQL: Optionally supports DUAL
> - Oracle: DUAL
> - Sybase SQL Anywhere: SYS.DUMMY
>
> Ingres has no DUAL, but would actually need it as in Ingres you cannot
>   have a WHERE, GROUP BY or HAVING clause without a FROM clause.

Answer (score 6):

You can.  I'm using the following lines in a [StackExchange Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/10747/how-many-votes-do-i-receive-per-answer):

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VotesOnPosts WHERE VoteTypeName = 'UpMod' AND UserId = @UserID AND PostTypeId = 2) AS TotalUpVotes,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Answers WHERE UserId = @UserID) AS TotalAnswers
```

The Data Exchange uses Transact-SQL (the SQL Server proprietary extensions to SQL).

You can try it yourself by running a query like:

```
SELECT 'Hello world'
```

Comment: The Data Exchange is Azure, based on SQL Server.

Answer (score 6):

In SQL Server type:

```
Select 'Your Text'
```

There is no need for the `FROM` or `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 4):

In Firebird, you can do this:

```
select "Hello world" from RDB$DATABASE;
```

RDB$DATABASE is a special table that always has one row.

Comment: This works for InterBase too (all versions).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but the best workaround for your question is using a dummy subquery:

```
SELECT 'Hello World'
FROM (SELECT name='Nothing') n
WHERE 1=1
```

This way you can have WHERE and any clause (like Joins or Apply, etc.) after the select statement since the dummy subquery forces the use of the FROM clause without changing the result.

Comment: You still have a `SELECT` without a `FROM` in your subquery, so it will still fail in Oracle, etc.

Comment: In Oracle is even simpler because you can just `SELECT 'Hello' FROM dual WHERE 1=1` and skip the subquery.

Comment: The OP asked if it was possible to have a statement (namely, a `SELECT`) without a `FROM` clause. Haven't you read the question?

Comment: I did read the question but unless you are totally inexperienced in SQL (or haven't read other answers) you know that you cannot have `WHERE` without `FROM`. Given that, I replied to the first statement of the OP question.

Comment: Well, I have more than 15 years experience in SQL, a Computing Degree and didn't remember if now having a `WHERE` was standard SQL. I read other answers also. By the way: the proper thing is that **you cannot have a `SELECT` without a `FROM`**, not "a `WHERE` without `FROM`" (?). Where does your query work, @DomingoR? It still has a `SELECT` without a `FROM` (in the subquery), thus failing on those DBMS that don't allow having queries without a `FROM` and working only on those which deviates from standard SQL and allow not having a `FROM` in the `SELECT`. So your answer serves for nothing.

Answer (score 3):

There is another possibility - standalone `VALUES()`:

```
VALUES ('Hello World');
```

Output:

```
column1
Hello World
```

---

It is useful when you need to specify multiple values in compact way:

```
VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c');
```

Output:

```
column1     column2
      1     a
      2     b
      3     c
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5190a2b1fbb5e7420422752cbbd1c579)**

This syntax is supported by SQLite/PostgreSQL/DB LUW/MariaDB 10.3.

Answer (score 3):

For ClickHouse, the nothing is `system.one`

```
SELECT 1 FROM system.one
```

Answer (score 2):

In Standard SQL, no. A `WHERE` clause implies a table expression.

From the SQL-92 spec:

> 7.6  "where clause"
>
> Function
>
> Specify a table derived by the
>   application of a "search condition" to
>   the result of the preceding "from
>   clause".

In turn:

> 7.4 "from clause"
>
> Function
>
> Specify a table derived from one or more named tables.

A Standard way of doing it (i.e. should work on any SQL product):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'Hello world' AS new_value
  FROM AnyTableWithOneOrMoreRows
 WHERE 1 = 1;
```

...assuming you want to change the `WHERE` clause to something more meaningful, otherwise it can be omitted.

Comment: ERROR:  column "hello world" does not exist in my_table
Query failed
PostgreSQL said: column "hello world" does not exist in my_table

Comment: @PålBrattberg: should be single quotes, now fixed.

Comment: Does it matter which table is used in terms of processing time? Or does the fact that the SELECT doesn't reference any of the columns make the actual table irrelevant?

Comment: @AllenGould: it would be 'vendor dependent' but there are obvious short circuits that could be exploited e.g. one case is where the optimizer recognizes the `SELECT` clause comprises constants only and that `AnyTableWithOneOrMoreRows` is a stored table, therefore merely uses statistics to verify whether the table has zero rows.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible. Theoretically: select performs two sorts of things:

- narrow/broaden the set (set-theory);
- mapping the result.

The first one can be seen as a horizontal diminishing opposed to the where-clause which can be seen as a vertical diminishing. On the other hand, a join can augment the set horizontally where a union can augment the set vertically.

```
               augmentation          diminishing
horizontal     join/select              select   
vertical          union            where/inner-join
```

The second one is a mapping. A mapping, is more a converter. In SQL it takes some fields and returns zero or more fields. In the select, you can use some aggregate functions like, sum, avg etc. Or take all the columnvalues an convert them to string. In C# linq, we say that a select accepts an object of type T and returns an object of type U.

I think the confusion comes by the fact that you can do: `select 'howdy' from <table_name>`. This feature is the mapping, the converter part of the select. You are not printing something, but converting! In your example:

```
SELECT "
WHERE 1 = 1
```

you are converting nothing/null into `"Hello world"` and you narrow the set of nothing / no table into one row, which, imho make no sense at all.

You may notice that, if you don't constrain the number of columns, `"Hello world"` is printed for each available row in the table. I hope, you understand why by now. Your select takes nothing from the available columns and creates one column with the text: `"Hello world"`.

So, my answer is NO. You can't just leave out the from-clause because the select always needs table-columns to perform on.

Answer (score 2):

For DB2:

```
`VALUES('Hello world')`
```

You can do multiple "rows" as well:

```
`VALUES('Hello world'),('Goodbye world');`
```

You can even use them in joins as long as the types match:

```
VALUES(1,'Hello world')
UNION ALL
VALUES(2,'Goodbye world');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using firebird
First of all, create a one column table named "NoTable" like this

```
CREATE TABLE NOTABLE 
(
  NOCOLUMN              INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO NOTABLE VALUES (0); -- You can put any value
```

now you can write this

```
select 'hello world' as name
```

from notable

you can add any column you want to be shown