# Oracle: how to INSERT if a row doesn't exist

Tags: oracle, plsql

What is the easiest way to INSERT a row if it doesn't exist, in PL/SQL (oracle)?

I want something like:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'jonny') THEN
  INSERT INTO table VALUES ("jonny", null);
END IF;
```

But it's not working.

Note: this table has 2 fields, say, **name** and **age**. But only **name** is PK.

Comment: Are you expecting that the INSERT statement will generally be necessary (i.e. the row generally will not exist)?  Or that the row generally will exist?

Comment: @justin: the row generally will NOT exist.

Comment: Cool.  Then any of the three options here should work for you.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table
SELECT 'jonny', NULL
  FROM dual -- Not Oracle? No need for dual, drop that line
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL -- canonical way, but you can select
                               -- anything as EXISTS only checks existence
                     FROM table
                    WHERE name = 'jonny'
                  )
```

Comment: @Jeff Walker: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732422/select-from-nothing/3732466#3732466)

Comment: dual is a dummy table in Oracle with one column and one row. It is bad (in SQLite you can just Select without from, in Oracle you have to use dual when selecting from nowhere).

Comment: -1 This will not work when more than one session tries to insert the same row at the same time - neither will see the other session's data until they commit, at which time it is too late. The best solution is to apply a unique constraint.

Comment: Late comment: @JeffreyKemp, there are use cases that do not require worrying about simultaneous sessions.

Comment: @JustinSkiles, those use cases are special cases and are irrelevant to this question. When a designer decides that a basic feature of the DBMS (in this case, concurrency) is not to be "worried about", that's exactly the bit that will bite their customers later on, most likely.

Comment: Simple and useful. Thanks @Benoit

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but will it not create any performance issue if the table is big ?

Comment: This seem to make infinite loop on DB.

Answer (score 36):

Assuming you are on 10g, you can also use the MERGE statement.  This allows you to insert the row if it doesn't exist and ignore the row if it does exist.  People tend to think of MERGE when they want to do an "upsert" (INSERT if the row doesn't exist and UPDATE if the row does exist) but the UPDATE part is optional now so it can also be used here.

```
SQL> create table foo (
  2    name varchar2(10) primary key,
  3    age  number
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  merge into foo a
  2    using (select 'johnny' name, null age from dual) b
  3       on (a.name = b.name)
  4   when not matched then
  5    insert( name, age)
  6*    values( b.name, b.age)
SQL> /

1 row merged.

SQL> /

0 rows merged.

SQL> select * from foo;

NAME              AGE
---------- ----------
johnny
```

Answer (score 18):

If name is a PK, then just insert and catch the error.  The reason to do this rather than any check is that it will work even with multiple clients inserting at the same time.  If you check and then insert, you have to hold a lock during that time, or expect the error anyway.

The code for this would be something like

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table( name, age )
    VALUES( 'johnny', null );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN dup_val_on_index
  THEN
    NULL; -- Intentionally ignore duplicates
END;
```

Comment: Code:`BEGIN INSERT INTO table VALUES('jonny', null);EXCEPTION WHEN sqlcode != -1 THEN RAISE;END; /`
sqlcode = -1 when ORA-00001

Comment: Whether it makes sense to try the insert and catch the exception depends on how frequently you expect the INSERT to succeed.  If 99% of the time you're inserting a non-duplicate value and it will only error out 1% of the time, catching and ignoring the exception is a good option.  If 99% of the time the row already exists, catching the exception can be problematic from a performance perspective.

Comment: Also, the merge method works with multiple rows in an insert ... select which this doesn't.  (I know the OP was doing a single row as an example but for this (and the performance issue sited by Justin Cave) I think merge is a better solution.

Answer (score 12):

I found the examples a bit tricky to follow for the situation where you want to ensure a row exists in the destination table (especially when you have two columns as the primary key), but the primary key might not exist there at all so there's nothing to select.

This is what worked for me:

```
MERGE INTO table1 D
    USING (
        -- These are the row(s) you want to insert.
        SELECT 
        'val1' AS FIELD_A,
        'val2' AS FIELD_B
        FROM DUAL

    ) S ON (
        -- This is the criteria to find the above row(s) in the
        -- destination table.  S refers to the rows in the SELECT
        -- statement above, D refers to the destination table.
        D.FIELD_A = S.FIELD_A
        AND D.FIELD_B = S.FIELD_B
    )

    -- This is the INSERT statement to run for each row that
    -- doesn't exist in the destination table.
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
        FIELD_A,
        FIELD_B,
        FIELD_C
    ) VALUES (
        S.FIELD_A,
        S.FIELD_B,
        'val3'
    )
```

The key points are:

- The `SELECT` statement inside the `USING` block must always return rows.  If there are no rows returned from this query, no rows will be inserted or updated.  Here I select from `DUAL` so there will always be exactly one row.
- The `ON` condition is what sets the criteria for matching rows.  If `ON` does not have a match then the INSERT statement is run.
- You can also add a `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE` clause if you want more control over the updates too.

Answer (score 11):

Using parts of @benoit answer, I will use this:

```
DECLARE
    varTmp NUMBER:=0;
BEGIN
    -- checks
    SELECT nvl((SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE name = 'john'), 0) INTO varTmp FROM dual;

    -- insert
    IF (varTmp = 1) THEN
        INSERT INTO table (john, null)
    END IF;

END;
```

Sorry for I don't use any full given answer, but I need `IF` check because my code is much more complex than this example table with name and age fields. I need a very clear code. Well thanks, I learned a lot! I'll accept @benoit answer.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the perfect and valid answers given so far, there is also the `ignore_row_on_dupkey_index` hint you might want to use:

```
create table tq84_a (
  name varchar2 (20) primary key,
  age  number
);

insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(tq84_a(name)) */ into tq84_a values ('Johnny',   77);
insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(tq84_a(name)) */ into tq84_a values ('Pete'  ,   28);
insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(tq84_a(name)) */ into tq84_a values ('Sue'   ,   35);
insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(tq84_a(name)) */ into tq84_a values ('Johnny', null);

select * from tq84_a;
```

The hint is described on [Tahiti](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF30052).

Answer (score 2):

**you can use this syntax:**

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( name, age )
select  'jonny', 18 from dual
where not exists(select 1 from table_name where name = 'jonny');
```

if its open an pop for asking as "enter substitution variable" then use this before the above queries:

```
set define off;
INSERT INTO table_name ( name, age )
select  'jonny', 18 from dual
where not exists(select 1 from table_name where name = 'jonny');
```

Comment: How is that different from the accepted answer posted three years ago already?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Merge:
For example:

```
MERGE INTO employees e
    USING (SELECT * FROM hr_records WHERE start_date > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1)) h
    ON (e.id = h.emp_id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET e.address = h.address
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, address)
    VALUES (h.emp_id, h.address);
```

or

```
MERGE INTO employees e
    USING hr_records h
    ON (e.id = h.emp_id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET e.address = h.address
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, address)
    VALUES (h.emp_id, h.address);
```

https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement

Comment: [https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/merge-enhancements-10g](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/merge-enhancements-10g)

Answer (score 0):

**CTE** and only **CTE** :-)

***just throw out extra stuff.*** Here is almost complete and verbose form for all cases of life. And you can use any concise form.

```
INSERT INTO reports r
  (r.id, r.name, r.key, r.param)
```

--

```
  -- Invoke this script from "WITH" to the end (";")
  -- to debug and see prepared values.
  WITH

  -- Some new data to add.
  newData AS(
          SELECT 'Name 1' name, 'key_new_1' key FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 'Name 2' NAME, 'key_new_2' key FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 'Name 3' NAME, 'key_new_3' key FROM DUAL
    ),
  -- Any single row for copying with each new row from "newData",
  -- if you will of course.
  copyData AS(
      SELECT r.*
      FROM reports r
      WHERE r.key = 'key_existing'
        -- ! Prevent more than one row to return.
        AND FALSE -- do something here for than!
    ),
  -- Last used ID from the "reports" table (it depends on your case).
  -- (not going to work with concurrent transactions)
  maxId AS (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM reports),
```

--

```
  -- Some construction of all data for insertion.
  SELECT maxId.id + ROWNUM, newData.name, newData.key, copyData.param
  FROM copyData
    -- matrix multiplication :)
    -- (or a recursion if you're imperative coder)
    CROSS JOIN newData
    CROSS JOIN maxId
```

--

```
  -- Let's prevent re-insertion.
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM reports rs
      WHERE rs.name IN(
        SELECT name FROM newData
      ));
```

I call it "**IF NOT EXISTS**" on steroids. So, this helps me and I mostly do so.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM reports` is not going to work with concurrent transactions

Comment: can you please offer something? I just don't know all stuff well.