# How to combine these four requests into one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to combine these four requests into one?

```
Select COUNT(Table1.statusID) as result1 from Table1 where Table1.emplDesignerID = 1135 and Table1.cancelled = 0
Select COUNT(Table1.statusID) as result2 from Table1 where Table1.emplDesignerID = 26 and Table1.cancelled = 0
Select COUNT(Table1.statusID) as result3 from Table1 where Table1.emplDesignerID = 1086 and Table1.cancelled = 0
Select COUNT(Table1.statusID) as result4 from Table1 where Table1.emplDesignerID = 1089 and Table1.cancelled = 0
```

I am using MS SQL Server.

Comment: Are you looking for UNION or IN statement??

Comment: Do you want the sum of these counts?

Comment: no, I don't want to get a sum

Comment: @Gennadyi which database are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SUM` and `CASE` can be usefully combined here:

```
Select
    SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.emplDesignerID = 1135 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as result1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.emplDesignerID = 26 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as result2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.emplDesignerID = 1086 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as result3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.emplDesignerID = 1089 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as result4
from Table1
where Table1.cancelled = 0
and Table1.emplDesignerID in (1135,26,1086,1089)
```

Depending on usage, you may or may not feel that the `IN` filter is required in the `WHERE` clause. There are other possible transforms (having `emplDesignerID` in the `SELECT` clause and `GROUP` ing on it) which may make it more flexible.

Comment: I cannot usefully edit this answer if nobody tells me what they consider makes it not useful.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I thought the original question was pulling from different tables (4 different tables). Please make a minor edit so I can revert my vote.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use sub queries and combine them into one larger query.

```
select
(
Select COUNT(Table1.statusID) as result1 from Table1 where Table1.emplDesignerID = 1135 and Table1.cancelled = 0
) as result1, 
(
Select COUNT(Table1.statusID) as result2 from Costs where Table1.emplDesignerID = 26 and Table1.cancelled = 0
) as result2,
(
Select COUNT(Table1.statusID) as result3 from Costs where Table1.emplDesignerID = 1086 and Table1.cancelled = 0
) as result3,
(
Select COUNT(Table1.statusID) as result4 from Costs where Table1.emplDesignerID = 1089 and Table1.cancelled = 0
) as result4;
```

If you are using Oracle you will have to add `from dual`.

Some other databases like MS SQL do not need it.

### Update - SQL-92 compliance

Oracle provides the dual table so the additional `from dual` can be added.
MS SQL provdes ability to query without a from statment.

See [SELECT from nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732422/select-from-nothing)

Or make us of the `Values` capability:

`select
    (
    Select COUNT(Table1.statusID) as result1 from Table1 where Table1.emplDesignerID = 1135 and Table1.cancelled = 0
    ) as result1, 
    (
    Select COUNT(Table1.statusID) as result2 from Costs where Table1.emplDesignerID = 26 and Table1.cancelled = 0
    ) as result2,
    (
    Select COUNT(Table1.statusID) as result3 from Costs where Table1.emplDesignerID = 1086 and Table1.cancelled = 0
    ) as result3,
    (
    Select COUNT(Table1.statusID) as result4 from Costs where Table1.emplDesignerID = 1089 and Table1.cancelled = 0
    ) as result4
    from
    (VALUES ('dummyValue'));`

Comment: I am not sure this is valid SQL

Comment: Depends on the database.

Comment: No dbms there. And it's not valid ANSI SQL anyway.

Comment: Almost ANSI SQL compliant. Add parentheses: `... from
(VALUES ('dummyValue'));`

Comment: Have a look @ SQL answer here as well...: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732422/select-from-nothing @jarlh

Comment: OP has now confirmed SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If count() is the only result you need you can use UNION :

```
Select COUNT(Table1.statusID) as result1 from Table1 where Table1.emplDesignerID = 1135 and Table1.cancelled = 0
UNION 
Select COUNT(Table1.statusID) as result2 from Table1 where Table1.emplDesignerID = 26 and Table1.cancelled = 0
UNION 
Select COUNT(Table1.statusID) as result3 from Table1 where Table1.emplDesignerID = 1086 and Table1.cancelled = 0
UNION 
Select COUNT(Table1.statusID) as result4 from Table1 where Table1.emplDesignerID = 1089 and Table1.cancelled = 0
```

it's quite easy to read but not the more efficient

Comment: Since `UNION` produces a result set using the column names from the first query, this will produce a result containing 4 rows in a `result1` column and no means to determine which result relates to which count.

Comment: Since UNION removes duplicates 1 to 4 rows can be returned. Do UNION ALL instead.