# Group By with Case Statement Doesn't Count Zeros

Tags: sql, join, group-by, db2, relational-database

I have the following SQL:

```
WITH MYFILTER AS (
SELECT
CASE WHEN STATE IN ('A', 'B') then
case
   when (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) < -0.3 then 'Less than -30%'
           when (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) >= -0.3
           and (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) < -0.2  then '-30% to -20%'
           when (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) >= -0.2
           and (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) < -0.1  then '-20% to -10%'
           when (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) >= -0.1
           and (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) < 0.0   then '-10% to 0%'
           when (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) >= 0.0
           and (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) < 0.1    then '0% to 10%'
           when (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) >= 0.1
           and (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) < 0.2    then '10% to 20%'
           when (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) >= 0.2
           and (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) < 0.3    then '20% to 30%'
           when (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) >= 0.3  THEN 'At least 30%'
           end
ELSE case
   when (NUM/DENOM < -0.3 then 'Less than -30%'
           when (NUM/DENOM >= -0.3
           and (NUM/DENOM < -0.2  then '-30% to -20%'
           when (NUM/DENOM >= -0.2
           and (NUM/DENOM < -0.1  then '-20% to -10%'
           when (NUM/DENOM >= -0.1
           and (NUM/DENOM < 0.0   then '-10% to 0%'
           when (NUM/DENOM >= 0.0
           and (NUM/DENOM < 0.1    then '0% to 10%'
           when (NUM/DENOM >= 0.1
           and (NUM/DENOM < 0.2    then '10% to 20%'
           when (NUM/DENOM >= 0.2
           and (NUM/DENOM < 0.3    then '20% to 30%'
           when (NUM/DENOM >= 0.3  THEN 'At least 30%'
           end
END AS indrange
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE DENOM <> 0 AND
YEAR = 2020 AND
MONTH = 11
)
SELECT
indrange,
count (*) AS total
FROM FILTER
GROUP BY indrange
```

Whenever the ratio doesn't fall into one of the ranges (say, for example, my table has no rows where NUM/DENOM - 1 > 0.3) then the result I end up with does not include "At least 30%" as a row with a 0 value. Instead, the row is is simply not present. How would I change the code so that it would still include the "At least 30%" row with a corresponding 0 value? In other words, I get this:

```
INDRANGE        TOTAL
Less than -30%  285
-30% to -20%    1,608
-20% to -10%    7,409
-10% to 0%      164,212
0% to 10%       169,665
10% to 20%      1
```

But I want this:

```
INDRANGE        TOTAL
Less than -30%  285
-30% to -20%    1,608
-20% to -10%    7,409
-10% to 0%      164,212
0% to 10%       169,665
10% to 20%      1
20% to 30%      0
At Least 30%    0
```

How can I do it? This is DB2.

Comment: in your CTE union in 1 row for each range, subtract 1 from results of each when you select from the CTE  `count(*)-1`  The issue is when you have no data matching the case expression you get no row.  To ensure you get all rows; union in a blank row for each possible range   however this increases your count by 1 for each range... so subtract 1 from each range on the select from the CTE.

Comment: @xQbert, I am strugging with the syntax for how do to this, could you please provide an example? Thank you.

Comment: example provided.  No enviornment to test so I'm unsure if I have all the syntax right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` between the ranges and your existing CTE. For example:

```
with myranges (indrange) as (
  select 'Less than -30%'         from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all select '-30% to -20%' from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all select '-20% to -10%' from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all select '-10% to 0%'   from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all select '0% to 10%'    from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all select '10% to 20%'   from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all select '20% to 30%'   from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all select 'At Least 30%' from sysibm.sysdummy1
),
myfilter as (
  -- here add you existing CTE
)
select r.indrange, count(f.indrange) AS total
from myranges r
left join myfilter f on f.indrange = r.indrange
group by r.indrange
```

Answer (score 2):

UNTESTED:  but something like this based on my prior comments.

- added a MyRanges cte listing each range 1 time thus ensuring each is included in the final query.
- Used Union all to combine it with results from MyFilter in the final query
- subtracted 1 from count(*) results since we inflated results by 1 from myRanges union

.

```
WITH  MYRANGES AS(
  SELECT 'Less than -30%' as INDRANGE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '-30% to -20%'    as INDRANGE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '-20% to -10%'    as INDRANGE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '-10% to 0%'      as INDRANGE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0% to 10%'       as INDRANGE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '10% to 20%'      as INDRANGE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '20% to 30%'      as INDRANGE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'At Least 30%'    as INDRANGE FROM DUAL),
MYFILTER AS (SELECT
  CASE WHEN STATE IN ('A', 'B') then
  case
   when (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) < -0.3 then 'Less than -30%'
           when (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) >= -0.3
           and (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) < -0.2  then '-30% to -20%'
           when (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) >= -0.2
           and (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) < -0.1  then '-20% to -10%'
           when (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) >= -0.1
           and (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) < 0.0   then '-10% to 0%'
           when (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) >= 0.0
           and (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) < 0.1    then '0% to 10%'
           when (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) >= 0.1
           and (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) < 0.2    then '10% to 20%'
           when (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) >= 0.2
           and (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) < 0.3    then '20% to 30%'
           when (NUM/DENOM - 1.0) >= 0.3  THEN 'At least 30%'
           end
ELSE case
   when (NUM/DENOM < -0.3 then 'Less than -30%'
           when (NUM/DENOM >= -0.3
           and (NUM/DENOM < -0.2  then '-30% to -20%'
           when (NUM/DENOM >= -0.2
           and (NUM/DENOM < -0.1  then '-20% to -10%'
           when (NUM/DENOM >= -0.1
           and (NUM/DENOM < 0.0   then '-10% to 0%'
           when (NUM/DENOM >= 0.0
           and (NUM/DENOM < 0.1    then '0% to 10%'
           when (NUM/DENOM >= 0.1
           and (NUM/DENOM < 0.2    then '10% to 20%'
           when (NUM/DENOM >= 0.2
           and (NUM/DENOM < 0.3    then '20% to 30%'
           when (NUM/DENOM >= 0.3  THEN 'At least 30%'
           end
END AS indrange
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE DENOM <> 0 AND
  YEAR = 2020 AND
  MONTH = 11
),

SELECT indrange, count (*)-1 AS total
FROM   (SELECT * FROM MyFilter UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM MyRanges) as MyFilterandAllRanges
GROUP BY indrange
```

Ok now that I've done something, I've thought about it and I can do better...

so modify the final query to be.... and we don't' have to mess with the numbers and math.  We're basically taking a "master list" of the ranges and outer joining it to our totals so that all ranges are always included and only those that have a match show a total.  We use coalesce to handle teh fact that some may not be there and substitute the needed 0.

```
SELECT MyRanges.indrange, coalesce(total,0) as total
FROM   MyRanges
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(*) total, Indrange 
           FROM MyFilter
           GROUP BY indrange) as sub
     on MyRanges.indrange = sub.indrange
```

Comment: FYI your CASE statements are unnecessarily complex as CASE statements stop processing when they hit first match. So, for example, you don't need "(NUM/DENOM - 1.0) >= -0.3" because any records that don't match this value will have been picked up by the first WHEN clause and will never reach this WHEN clause

Comment: @nickW I'm using the case expressions from the original post.  I'm not trying to improve or comment on it; just address the problem presented. (id' say that comment belongs against the original post more than the answer :P)

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting an error saying "Dual" is an undefined name. I did a quick google search and didn't come up with much for this. Does the Dual keyword work in DB2? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: In DB2 you can use `sysibm.sysdummy1` in place of `dual`.

Comment: and I thought DB2 supported dual based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732422/select-from-nothing oh well.